# PHP PDO SQL Server cannot connect via Ubuntu terminal

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu, pdo

I have one php script want to connect with SQL Server database using PDO. The connection is working with the browser, however, when I run it on the terminal, it shows the error message: "Could not find driver". On the phpinfo. The reason I want to run it by terminal is I want to use it on crontab. But the connection is failed. I can see the PDO with sqlsrv driver has already installed, and if it's working with browser, that should work for terminal too. There is only one PHP installed on the Ubuntu server. Can someone help me?

[image]

Edit:

I can see the phpinfo php.ini is from fpm folder, and I compared this php.ini with the one under cli folder and found they're almost same.

[image]

Comment: Likely your CLI version of PHP is different. What does `php -i | grep 'pdo' -i` return?

Comment: ```/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini,
API Extensions => mysqli,pdo_mysql
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, pgsql, sqlite
pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pdo_pgsql
PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled
pdo_sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled```

Can you see anything wrong?

Comment: There is no `sqlsrv` listed there. You only have support for `mysql`.

Comment: Do you mean I should install sqlsrv to this cli? I checked the php.ini, and there is no much different. However, I do see under conf.d foder of cli, there is missing the one, 20-pdo_sqlsrv.ini， which is in the fpm folder.

Comment: If the apache one works I would just change the CLI to use that one. Then you won't have issues in the future with different versions either. https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214202148-How-do-I-change-the-PHP-version-my-shell-uses- This also presume you aren't using Dev settings in one and prod in the other.

Comment: so how should I "change the CLI to use that one"? Should I just copy that missing 20-pdo_sqlsrv.ini into the cli conf.d folder?